# Can mounts on Vivitar 75-205mm lenses be swapped?

Tags: lens, repair, old-lenses

I have a Vivitar 75-205mm f/3.8 MC Macro Focusing Zoom Lens with a Minolta MD mount.

Would the Nikon AI Mount from the same lens (Vivitar 75-205mm f/3.8 MC Macro Focusing Zoom Lens Nikon AI Mount) interchange with my lens?

I can purchase the damaged lens (w/ Nikon mount) for $6.00.

Cameras - Nikon D40X and D3200.  Lens with MD mount is practically new, still in the box.  Lens w/ Nikon mount has aperture issues, damaged l.ens and bent filter ring.

Comment: Might be - check if you can get a service manual on one of the usual sites (butkus etc.), some of these lenses are indeed modular in construction.... the 70-210/f3.5 (kino precision) is known to be...

Answer (score 2):

**The only way to know for certain whether the mounts can be switched is to try.**  You may even find that the "damaged" lens is perfectly usable as is.

**If the lenses are the same model** with different mounts, **it is likely they share much of the same construction** so that the mounts can be switched.  However, different mounts often have mechanical linkages that work differently, which could complicate switching them.

If you do try to switch the mounts, **the aperture ring will likely have to be switched as well**. Take care not to lose any parts, such as the ball bearing that gives the aperture its click.

**If you can find service manuals**, you may be able to determine whether it is worth the effort.

- [Camera Manual Library](http://OrphanCameras.com) ([butkus.org](https://www.butkus.org/chinon/) / [butkus.us](https://www.butkus.us/))
- [Boggy's Web Site](http://boggys.co.uk) - Kiron, Vivitar, Panagor